# r.js optimization is not preserving paths

Tags: javascript, requirejs, r.js

I'm using r.js optimization with CDN assets set to :empty in the paths configuration. However, when I hit the optimized file, require is not fetching the CDN assets. Specifically it is not reaching out for jQuery. I'm also using the grunt requirejs task.

Here is my require.js config:

```
require.config({
  paths: {
    jquery               :'//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min'
  }
});
```

And here is the grunt.js config:

```
    requirejs: {
        compile: {
            options: {
                baseUrl: "public/resources/javascripts/",
                mainConfigFile: "public/resources/javascripts/main.js",
                out: "public/resources/javascripts/main-build.js",
                paths: {
                    'jquery': 'empty:'
                },
                name: "main",
                generateSourceMaps: true,
                optimize: "uglify2",
                preserveLicenseComments: false
            }
        }
    }
```

And I'm hitting the built asset as:

```
<script data-main="/resources/javascripts/main-build.js" src="/resources/javascripts/libs/require.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must add the resources loaded from a CDN inside the `exclude` array too. Otherwise, the module is included, simply empty.

```
exclude: [ "jquery" ]
```

On a side note, loading jQuery from a CDN will be slower than bundling it into your builded file. You shouldn't use a CDN in this case.

Comment: And the exclude attribute goes in the grunt.js config?

Comment: Yeah, the browser is still not fetching jQuery for some reason when using the optimized main-build.js. I've included it in the exclude as you mentioned. Thanks!